# Можно ли получить ссылку на фото удаленного ответа ask fm?

Tags: url, веб-сервер, веб-служба

Известно что все фото вечно хранятся на серваках ask fm - нужно лишь иметь прямую ссылку. В кэше гугла и яндекса а также других систем нужной страницы нет. Можно ли как-нибудь получить ссылку на фотографию ответа пользователя?
Может у вас есть какие-то предположения как генерируется url с параметром get запроса? Примеры ссылок:
http://pastebin.com/pk7YvVH3
Если еще нужны примеры вот откуда можно брать - ask.fm/askfm